# Catching Spring Integration DSL misconfiguration exceptions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Is there a way to catch `DestinationResolutionException` and `MessageDispatchingException` when using DSL? These exceptions usually indicate misconfiguration but I am not sure how I could configure my flow to catch these exceptions and apply some custom logic?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class IntegrationMisconfigurationExampleApplication {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(IntegrationMisconfigurationExampleApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow loggingFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("input")
        .<String, String>transform(String::toUpperCase)
        // .nullChannel();
        .get();
  }

  @Bean
  public CommandLineRunner demo() {
    return args -> {
      final MessagingTemplate template = messagingTemplate();
      template.convertAndSend("input", "abc");
    };
  }

  @Bean
  public MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate() {
    return new MessagingTemplate();
  }
}
```

The example above throws a `DestinationResolutionException` because `loggingFlow.transformer#0` is not properly initialized. Is there a way to catch this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those exceptions are *runtime* errors. We really can't determine a misconfiguration at startup.

The way to catch runtime exception like that and do some analyzing work is with the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`, which you can add to your `transform(String::toUpperCase)` configuration in the second argument for endpoint configuration:

```
.<String, String>transform(String::toUpperCase, e-> e.advice(myExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice()))
```

See more info about this advice in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#message-handler-advice-chain

Also you need to keep in mind that `transformer` is really a *request-reply* component with required non-null return value. Therefore you really can't configure a `transform()` just for one-way flow. It is going to throw an exception when there is no next channel in the flow or no `replyChannel` header in the message.

Comment: I should have explained better what I was trying to do... I deliberately misconfigured the transformer as it was the easiest way I know how to produce this exception. I am also aware that you cannot determine it and wasn't expecting you to, I was really looking for `e.advice` :) I tried looking for `e.errorChannel(...)` or something similar and couldn't find one, didn't think about using advices, thanks!

Comment: The `errorChannel()` works only form Gateway or Inbound Channel Adapter. And it is still is like a header in the request message. Such an error is handled on that inbound component. But if you send message directly, you'll get an exception in the caller. Only the way to process it locally in the current component is via the mentioned advice.

Comment: Just one more thing, is it possible to register an Advice for the complete flow, not just one component? So in case of multiple `.transform(...)` methods I don't have to register advice for each of them? This might warrant a new question?

Comment: No, that's not. Such an advice is per endpoint. The whole flow is just a logical container and there is nothing at runtime in regards for interaction between flow and it declared endpoints.